# Java string calculator, first number is negative

Tags: java, regex, string, calculator

So i have this code which i took from another question and its never answered, how would i have to change the code if String a = "-5+20-15+8" with the first number being negative, right now it gives an error.

```
 String a = "5+20-15+8";
    System.out.println(a);
    String operators[]=a.split("[0-9]+");
    String operands[]=a.split("[+-]");
    int agregate = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<operands.length;i++){
        if(operators[i].equals("+"))
            agregate += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
        else 
            agregate -= Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(agregate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way to fix it is to make sure you don't split at the first `-` when you split the string into operands.

```
String operands[]=a.split("(?<=\\d)[+-]");
```

This regex asserts that the `+` or `-` must be followed by a digit.

This way, the first operand would be `-5`, which would then be correctly parsed by `Integer.parseInt`.

If you only need to handle addition and subtraction, here's another way to think about the problem: there are no operators, only operands. In `-5+20-15+8`, there are only the operands `-5`, `+20`, `-15`, `+8`, and you just need to add them all up. We can split the string into operands at a digit-`[+-]` boundary:

```
String[] operands = a.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[+-])");
```

and then just sum them all up:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < operands.length ; i++) {
    result += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
}
// or:
// int result = Arrays.stream(operands).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: if i want to allow spaces between numbers like: -2  - 2   + 4-5, how should i go about it?

Comment: @Valch a simple way would be remove all the spaces with a regex first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `-` and `+` used as separators so the first `-` in `-5` will interpreted as such wrongly. Quick solution is to expect that those two operator must have spaces around them, thus they differentiate themselfs from the case when they represent the sign.

```
public class Main {
     public static void main(String []args){
         String a = "-5 + 20 - 15 + 8";
            System.out.println(a);
            String operators[]=a.split("[0-9]+");
            String operands[]=a.split(" [+-] ");
            int agregate = Integer.parseInt(operands[0]);
            for(int i=1;i<operands.length;i++){
                if(operators[i].equals(" + "))
                    agregate += Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
                else 
                    agregate -= Integer.parseInt(operands[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(agregate);
     }
}
```

Comment: @DeepakJasawat "expect that those two operator must have spaces around them" I did not said they will.